# Using jQuery do sorting in gridview of .NET?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, gridview, sorting

Need Example of jquery for sorting... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin or looking at the code there for ideas on how to implement it?